# Displaying HTML div at a certain time and day of the week

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner coder and I mostly focus on HTML. I'm currently working on a website for my friend's radio show. Now I want to display a certain div at a certain time and day of the week, Wednesday from 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM EST. I know this probably involves JavaScript so I searched around and found this. But for some reason during the time stated I'm getting the opposite result.

```js
var Now = new Date();
var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
// opening time - military time so 5:00pm is 17, 00
var OpeningTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 17, 00);
// closing time - military time so 6:00pm is 18, 00
var ClosingTime = new Date(Now.getFullYear(), Now.getMonth(), Now.getDate(), 19, 00);
var Open = (Now.getTime() > OpeningTime.getTime() && Now.getTime() < ClosingTime.getTime())
// days 0.sun 1.mon 2.tues 3.wed 4.thur 5.fri 6.sat 
// CurrentDay !== 0 && the # is the day to eclude, so if I want to be closed on Sat6, Sun0, Wed3
// CurrentDay !== 6 && CurrentDay !== 0 && CurrentDay !== 3 && Open
if (CurrentDay !== 0 && CurrentDay !== 1 && CurrentDay !== 2 && CurrentDay !== 4 && CurrentDay !== 5 && CurrentDay !== 6 && Open) {
  $('.openstatus').toggle();
}
```

```html
<div class="hours openstatus">Radio-show is live</div>
<div class="closed openstatus">Tune in at Wednesday from 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM</div>
```

Comment: uses `if(matched){$('.openstatus').show();}else{$('.openstatus').hide();}`; [.toggle()  Description: Display or hide the matched elements.](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: insetead of using 6 not equal statements, you should just use one equals statement.

If you are getting the opposite result of what you want, change it from `!==` to `===` instead.

Comment: From what you are saying, you should be using `show()` instead of `toggle()`.  It also sounds like you need to modify your css for .openstatus to be `display: none;` so that it is hidden by default

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your Javascript quite a bit by using:

```
if (new Date().getDay() === 3 && open) {
  $('.openstatus').show();
}
```

You might also need to do something like add class 'hidden' to your div, or change your css to have `.closed { display: none; }`

Also just by convention all of your variables should follow `camelCase` instead of starting with capital letters.